# Программная обработка bottomsheetbehavior

Tags: java, android, listener, android-material, android-bottomsheetbehavior

есть приложение и оно как бы все работает, только не получается прикрутить bottomsheetbehavior - постоянно вылетает в строчке изменения состояния. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.activity_main;
private static final int THEME_LAYOUT = R.style.AppDefault;

private BottomFragmentSetting bottomFragmentSetting;

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(THEME_LAYOUT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(LAYOUT);

    bottomFragmentSetting = new BottomFragmentSetting();
    initToolbar();
    initTabLayout();
}

private void initToolbar(){
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.settingFiltr:
                //i'm need help in using change bottomSheetBehavior state

                //bottomFragmentSetting.show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
}

private void initTabLayout() {
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    TabsPagerFragmentAdapter tabsPagerFragmentAdapter = new 
    TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerFragmentAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(Constants.TAB_ONE);

    TabLayout tabLayout  = findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutMain);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
   }
}
```

Вот код обработчика:

```
public class BottomFragmentSetting extends AppCompatActivity {
public BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
public LinearLayout linearLayout;

public void show(){
    if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) 
{
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
} else {
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_dialog_filtr);

linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(linearLayout);
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
//bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(340);
bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);

bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new 
BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {

 bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

    }
});
```

}
   }

Если нужно больше кода - вот весь проект на github: [проект](https://github.com/Divinkas/tst.git)

Спасибо огромное заранее!

Comment: можно код ошибки еще?

Comment: В прочем кажется кода не нужно) На экране может быть только 1 активити. Вы пробуете изменить UI активити № 1 из активити № 2. Так делать нельзя

Comment: Как тогда - убрать наследование от AppCompatActivity и сделать простым классом? (У мейн активити ботом просто инклудится)

Comment: думаю, вам нужно оформить его в виде фрагмента (наследовать от Fragment).

Comment: изменил - все равно падает на том же месте, с той же ошибкой. Вот сркин (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z2YnZcMNazBkZQh1rq1PrdtPFuP56gpS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Это вот эта строчка  if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что `onCreate` у класса `BottomFragmentSetting` не выполняется, так как Вы его создали не системными средствами. Но в Вашем случае этот класс не должен быть ни активностью ни фрагментом, так как `BottomSheetBehavior` управляет частью разметки активности, а не отдельным компонентом.
Вам нужно перенести код в конструктор класса:

```
public class BottomFragmentSetting { // наследование не нужно
    public BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public void show(){
        // Ваш код
    }

    public BottomFragmentSetting(Activity activity) {
        linearLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(linearLayout);
        // остальной код из onCreate
    }
}
```

И в `MainActivity` создаём класс так:

```
bottomFragmentSetting = new BottomFragmentSetting(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает!:)